# Qt plugandpaint example. Zoom in and out

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I am trying to modify the qt plug and paint example. I would like to zoom the photo in and out. All object need to be resized with the photo. (I am going to draw an image, points and polygons.)

Currently I made a zoomIn(), zoomOut() and scaleView() methods.

```
void PaintArea::scaleView(qreal scaleFactor)
{
    qreal factor = transform().scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor).mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)).width();      //this line give the error that there is no transform()
    if (factor < 0.07 || factor > 100)
        return;

    this->scaleView(factor);
}

void PaintArea::zoomIn()
{
    scaleView(qreal(1.2));
}

void PaintArea::zoomOut()
{
    scaleView(1 / qreal(1.2));
}
```

Comment: What is the requirement ?

Comment: @TheApache I would like to load a photo and draw qpolygons and qpoints on top of the image. The qpoints need to be movable. The photo is in no case allowed to move, but when zoomed in all the items (polygons and points) should scale along with the photo. Other than that there are no requirements.
If you know a way to draw on top of the ImageViewer example, that should work too.